# Sitecore Solr - Content Editor search returns no results but Experience editor and context search works fine

Tags: solr, content-search, content-editor

We are having the following issue. Please let me know if you have come across a similar issue or know of a potential solution.

In Sitecore `Content Editor`, all search queries works fine if logged in as admin.
For non Admin users, we have 3 different scenarios.

- Experience Editor search works fine.
- Context search in content editor from right side works fine.
  [image]
- Content Editor search on left side returns no results

[image]

We have content tree restriction for the non admin user but we are searching for terms where the user has access to the content. We have tried with very frequent used words and alphabets also, but no results show up on content editor search.

No errors logged in Sitecore log file, Sitecore search log and 'Solr' log files.

We are running our instance on `Sitecore 8.2`.

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72854929/sitecore-content-tree-search-taking-personalization-index-instead-of-master-inde

Comment: Hello @SumitBhatia, I can see the solr queries being generated for master index from the logs

Comment: Hello @MarekMusielak, Yes. They are on the root content item when trying to search. which gives result on the right context search but not on the left content editor search

Comment: When you compare in `search.log` query generated for admin and non-admin users, are they the same?

Comment: @MarekMusielak, Yes. They are exact same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote in your comment, Solr query generated for admin and non-admin users are the same.

I don't expect that you have any customizations for build in checks of security in Solr, so that would mean that for both admin and non-admin, Solr returns same results.

That means that some results are omitted on purpose by Sitecore, while converting Solr search results into what is shown in Content Editor.

The search logic happens in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Client.Pipelines.Search.SearchContentSearchIndex`. From what I can see, the only reason why some search results are shown for Admin and hidden for non-admin users is if that non-admin user doesn't have `Hidden items` checked in `VIEW` ribbon:

[image]

You may want to check that one.

And if that's not the case, I suggest you decompile the class and replace original with your decompiled version and debug it (or debug Sitecore code if possible for you https://subbu.ca/blogs/debug-sitecore-dlls-made-easy-with-in-built-visual-studio-decompiler-and-symbol-generator/ )

Comment: Hello @Marek Thanks for pointing out the "Hidden Items" checkbox. We tried enabling this for the content authors and they are able to view the search results. For Admin obviously this was checked and it stopped working for admin users, when this is un checked. Now I have checked the items and those were not set to be hidden. and this search result behavior is same for all across content tree. Could you provide any more insights how this could happen ?

Comment: Is any of the ancestors hidden? in `Appearance` section `Hidden` checkbox? `/sitecore` or `/sitecore/content` item or any other ancestor of your items?

Comment: Thanks Marek, the root /sitecore item was marked as hidden some how and that seems to be the root cause. Thanks for spending time analyzing the specific issue and providing helpful debug information which helped in finding the root cause and fix it. Thanks again.